# How can I install libgfortran3 in Ubuntu/Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, blas, ubuntu-20.04, jblas

I'm using jBlas and it require libgfortran3 and tell me to install it from:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
```

But I'm using Lubuntu 20.04, which use the same packages as Ubuntu 20.04. I can't find the package here 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgfortran3

So what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, `libgfortran3` is no longer supported in Ubuntu 20.04. It depends on an older version of `gcc` which is no longer maintained in this version of the distribution.

As an alternative, you might want to try installing its successor package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran5
```

It will provide these [files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libgfortran5/filelist) for your Ubuntu installation:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran5
```

This way, you have an option of dynamically loading/linking against `libgfortran` at runtime.

Hope it helps.

Comment: some old software are depending on the libgfortran3 only...

Comment: Well, that is neither a problem of the OS nor the environment, yet of the "old software" itself. If source code is available: modernize it. If not: discard it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `libgfortran3`, you can just copy a `libgfortran.so.3` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.
It works for me.